# Xenserver 6.2: error "There is not enough space to upload the update"

Tags: xenserver, citrix

Xenserver upload update/patch, there is not enough space to upload the update. After uploading many patches, Xen gave me this error "there is not enough space to upload the update" and when I check on "/Var/patch" I see only "applied patches".

What could be taking all the space in the server, how can I delete or remove the old patches?

How can i cleanup xen and apply the pending updates?

Answer (score 1):

- You can clean everything under `/opt/xensource/patch-backup`
- Also you can clean the old logs in `/var/log` using "`rm -rf *.gz`"